# Retrofit + Dagger + Timeouts

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, dagger

I understand that it is best to use singleton pattern for retrofit object. I usually will reuse the Service Interface object instead of retrofit.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
RestAPIService providesRestAPIService(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(RestAPIService.class);
}
```

However, there's a requirement in my project now where I have different KPI for each different endpoint (submission APIs use 40sec read timeout, whereas retrieval APIs having 10 sec and validation APIs having 20 sec read timeout).

So what is the proper way to use DI for multiple diff read timeout scenario? Should I create multiple Okhttp instances or multiple Retrofit instances or multiple API instances?

Comment: rather than setting the values directly you can create a class and in that class define an initial value for the timeout and create a getter and setter for it and set the timeout through this getter and when you need to change the timeout set the other timeout thorough setter

Comment: Use a factory, to create separate instances of okhttp for differing kpi. Using a singleton is too risky as potentially one thread could be using said singleton with one timeout value, and the other thread using different time out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dagger2 to create multiple instances of Retrofit using `@Named` annotation. You can change the readtimeout, writetimeout accordingly.

```
@Provides
@Named("myapi1retrofit")
Retrofit provideRetro() {
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .baseUrl("http://api1.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
}

@Provides
@Named("myapi2retrofit")
Retrofit provideRetro() {
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .baseUrl("http://api2.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
}


@Provides
@Named("myapi1service")
public RestAPIService providesRestService(@Named("myapi1retrofit") Retrofit retrofit) {
return retrofit.create(RestAPIService.class);
}


@Provides
@Named("myapi1service")
public RestAPIService providesRestService(@Named("myapi2retrofit") Retrofit retrofit) {
return retrofit.create(RestAPIService.class);
}
```